# Is it frowned upon to not show your face during virtual meetings?

Tags: meetings

Is it frowned upon to not show your face during virtual meetings? Or does it depend on the company culture?

Comment: I think you're getting down votes because this is a very opinion based question and you're generally requested to give specific and actionable questions.

Comment: It depends. For me, if the host or the interviewers do not show their faces and only play their voice during the meeting for some reason, then I would do the same (and they always agree that I should do the exact same thing as they do).  Just follow what the host/interviewers do, and you will be fine.

Answer (score 3):

The only way to know is to ask.

The person to ask is your manager, for large meetings, or the organizer for smaller meetings.

Some general rules:

If Bandwidth is a concern, it is customary to leave the camera off.
If not, then ask if you should have your camera on.

For larger meetings, the default is "off", smaller meetings, watch what others do.

If you are the only one with your camera off, then yeah, it would be bad form

Comment: Yup. Ask... any suggestion of whom should OP ask this?

Comment: @DarkCygnus edited